# position div to bottom of containing div

Tags: css, position

How can i position a div to the bottom of the containing div?

```
<style>
.outside {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #EEE; /*to make it visible*/
}
.inside {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
}
</style>
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">inside</div>
</div>
```

This code puts the text "inside" to the bottom of the page.

Comment: .outside needs `position: relative;`

Comment: relative, yes, and then it doesn't know how large it needs to be to hold the child-div content, unfortunately, so unless that is a static-value, back to the original question.  How to place one div at the bottom of another div (implied: "without breaking everything").

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
.outside {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #EEE; /*to make it visible*/
}
```

Needs to be

```
.outside {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #EEE; /*to make it visible*/
}
```

Absolute positioning looks for the nearest relatively positioned parent within the DOM, if one isn't defined it will use the body.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why?

Comment: `absolute` searches for the nearest `relative` parent. By default it's the `body` of the `document`. So if no parent DOM object (`.outside`) has the property of being `relative` your `.inside` will go to to the bottom of the body tag.

Comment: "*Absolute positioning looks for the nearest relatively positioned parent within the DOM, if one isn't defined it will use the body.*" You just explained **so** much for me! Now I really start to understand CSS. ***THANK YOU!***

Comment: Absolute actually searches for the nearest non default (= static) positioned ancestor, which is often relatively positioned. It also doesn't have to be a direct parent but can for example be a grandparent.

Comment: This depends on constant heights, which is VERY BAD. A simple change of font, font size, padding, margins and god knows what else demands experimentation to guess the new height.

Comment: @Anderson It's not important to give values to `width` and `height` parameters in implement the above given functionality. You can calculate exclude both of these parameters and it will just work fine.

Comment: Somehow above code doesn't work in firefox. If you give height as 100%. Any suggestion over this?

Answer (score 75):

Assign `position:relative` to `.outside`, and then `position:absolute; bottom:0;` to your `.inside`.

Like so:

```
.outside {
    position:relative;
}
.inside {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: this could be the basis for a sticky footer couldn't it?

Comment: I can not use position: absolute; for second div. that is my restriction, can you give me other options?

Answer (score 20):

Add `position: relative` to `.outside`. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

The "initial container" would be `<body>`, but adding the above makes `.outside` positioned.