# Absoloute position div to bottom of relative parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place 'blue' at the bottom of the parent container 'green'. I've tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358646/css-position-div-to-bottom-of-containing-div), but can't get it to work. I want the blue div to be at the bottom of the green div.

```css
#green {
 position:relative;
 width:auto;
 height:200px;
 background-color:green;
}  



#blue {
 position:absoloute;
 bottom:0;
 height:75px;
 width:auto;
 background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="green">
 <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Change `absoloute` to `absolute`.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the typo and set the width to 100% and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- You need to change position absoloute to absolute of #blue, then after width auto to width 100%.

```
#blue {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is an working example for you http://codepen.io/saorabhkr/pen/BoQjvN