# Position element at bottom of div

Tags: html, css, css-position

Does anyone know a way to have a footer stuck to the bottom of a div like a `position: fixed` element. The methods I've found all stick it at the bottom of the starting view or at the bottom so you have to scroll all the way down to see them.

I have tried setting the parent to `position:relative` and the child to `position: absolute`, and also using `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom`, but neither keep it stuck in place as you scroll, instead they leave it static at the bottom of the div or at the bottom of the default view.

```css
.a{
  position:relative;
  background-color:#ccc;
  width:500px;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float:left;
  padding:8px;
}

.footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#666;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />
    <div class="footer">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS positioning "float: bottom"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/html-css-positioning-float-bottom) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358646/css-position-div-to-bottom-of-containing-div

Comment: it isn't, the answers for that don't show locking the item to the bottom of the div

Comment: It sort of is. Its really the only effective way of doing it.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate; it's related, but the OP's question is a bit more specific since his element `overflow: scroll`. Also, the solution is different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't really, not the way you want to, and you'd need to use jquery to keep moving the position.

What you can do, which is the easiest solution, is to have a container wrapping the entire area.

```
.outer {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
}

.a{
  background-color:#ccc;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding:8px;
}

.footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#666;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="a">
       Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />Some content<br />
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Some text</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Trying to modify my markup and styling to allow that. The first thing I tried was that, but I was unable to move the footer out of the a without it breaking a ton of styling.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you can't use `position: fixed` on an element (only works on [viewport](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)), but you want the `footer` element to sit in a `fixed` position relative to it's parent.

You can do that by wrapping the scrollable `div` and setting the `footer` to the bottom of that `wrap` element. Since the `wrap` doesn't scroll (the element inside of it does), the `footer` won't move when you scroll.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebgfjcLL/1/).

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
    background-color:#ccc;
    position: relative;
}

.a {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.b {
    margin-top: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:#666;
  color:#fff;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="a">
        top
        <div class="b">bottom</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Some text</div>
</div>
```