# How to lock an element to the bottom of a div that is in a container (square)?

Tags: html, css

```css
 * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      .publication {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 6%;
      }
      
      .bottom1,
      .bottom2 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      
      .bottom1 {
        width: 70%;
      }
      
      .publicationleft {
        width: 700px;
        height: 130px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding: 15px;
        background: #C7D3DF;
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      
      .publicationbottom {
        width: 700px;
        height: 70px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding: 15px;
        background: #769DBD;
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        padding-top: 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      .textpub {
        color: #365A6B;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      
      .link {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="bottom1">
    
      <div class="publicationleft">
    
        <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo </div>
    
        <div class="link"><a href="https://www.google.com/"><font color="white">Link</font></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="publicationleft">
        <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo </div>
    
        <a href="https://www.google.com/"><font color="white">Link</font></a>
      </div>
      <div class="publicationleft">
        <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo.</div>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/"><font color="white">Link</font></a>
      </div>
      <div class="publicationleft">
        <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo </div>
    
        <a href="https://www.google.com/"><font color="white">Link</font></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How to lock an an element ***(link in this case)*** to the bottom-left of a div 
***(rounded square in this case)*** ?

So basically, the link has to be locked bottom-left of the rounded square.

Anyone knows a solution ?
I tried it with positsion: relative. Didn't work. It keeps going to the very bottom of the container.

Comment: sorry i could not understand what you need? please briefly describe.

Comment: So you have the lightblue squares where some text and a link is displayed on. Right now the link is below the text. I want the link to permanently stay at the very bot of the blue square, no matter what. I don't want to use p tag or anyting.

Comment: .link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
} and .publicationleft{position:relative;}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css - position div to bottom of containing div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358646/css-position-div-to-bottom-of-containing-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I suppose you want to absolutely position the "link" at the bottom of its parent. For that to wor, simply use:

```
.link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Note that you will also have to set the parent to `position: relative`:

```
.publicationleft {
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is your proof-of-concept example:

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      .publication {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 6%;
      }
      
      .bottom1,
      .bottom2 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      
      .bottom1 {
        width: 70%;
      }
      
      .publicationleft {
        width: 700px;
        height: 130px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding: 15px;
        background: #C7D3DF;
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        
        /* To allow link to be absolutely positioned */
        position: relative;
      }
      
      .publicationbottom {
        width: 700px;
        height: 70px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding: 15px;
        background: #769DBD;
        color: #fff;
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        padding-top: 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      .textpub {
        color: #365A6B;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      
      .link {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div class="bottom1">
    
      <div class="publicationleft">
    
        <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo </div>
    
        <div class="link"><a href="https://www.google.com/"><font color="white">Link</font></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="publicationleft">
        <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo </div>
    
        <a href="https://www.google.com/"><font color="white">Link</font></a>
      </div>
      <div class="publicationleft">
        <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo.</div>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/"><font color="white">Link</font></a>
      </div>
      <div class="publicationleft">
        <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo </div>
    
        <a href="https://www.google.com/"><font color="white">Link</font></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Muhammad Well he said this in the question: "How to lock an an element (link in this case) to **the bottom-left of a div** (rounded square in this case) ?" (emphasis mine). I think you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: your are right. take a vote from me for the nice solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can inbricate flexbox and use align-self or margins :
update :

```
bottom1,
.bottom2,
.publicationleft/* added */ {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.link {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: auto;/* or align-self:flex-end */
  border:solid;/*see me for demo*/
 /*bottom:0; removed */
 /* text-align:right; optionnal */
}
```

Demo below

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.publication {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6%;
}

.bottom1,
.bottom2,
.publicationleft {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom1 {
  width: 70%;
}

.publicationleft {
  width: 700px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #C7D3DF;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.publicationbottom {
  width: 700px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #769DBD;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.textpub {
  color: #365A6B;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.link {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: auto;/* or lign-self:flex-end */
  border:solid;/*see me for demo*/
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom1">

  <div class="publicationleft">

    <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo </div>

    <div class="link">
      <a href="https://www.google.com/">
        <font color="white">Link</font>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="publicationleft">
    <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo </div>

    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <font color="white">Link</font>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="publicationleft">
    <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo.</div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <font color="white">Link</font>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="publicationleft">
    <div class="textpub">FamoS – Fahrradverkehrsmodelle als Planungsinstrument zur Reorganisation des Straßenraums (2016-2018) Unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Radverkehrs werden multimo </div>

    <a href="https://www.google.com/" >
      <font color="white">Link</font>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the way you'd want to go about this is to set your parent container (in this case `publicationleft`) to:

```
position: relative;
```

Then for your child container (in this case `link`), you would use:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

You can learn more about this method [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

Answer (score 0):

Replace below two styles with this

```
.publicationleft {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 130px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #C7D3DF;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```